# Inserting Data Into a 2D Array Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

Basically I'm trying to insert a number into a 2D array like this:

arrayName[X][Y] = 4;

but I get an error that says:

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

so how do I fix this or do it properly?

Comment: The error is trying to tell you that the inner Array doesn't exist at index `X`. Show us how you created the 2D Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arrFirst:Array = [];
var arrSecond:Array = [];
arrSecond[Y] = 4;
arrFirst[X] = arrSecond;
```